# reinterpret_cast memory not modified

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I tried to modify an object of `A` indirectly by allocating 8 bytes using `std::allocator`. I used `<int>` specifically, hoping it will return aligned memory for 2 integers. Then I modified an object of `A`.

Why do I only see `A.x=9` in the `bitset` (towards the end 1001), what happened to `A.y=10`? Do I need to align the raw pointer returned by `std::allocator`?

I was expecting the output below:

```
0000000000000000000000000000100100000000000000000000000000001010
```

```
before=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
---------------------
sizeof(A)=8
alignof(A)=4
x: 9 y: 10
---------------------
x: 9 y: 10
after=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001
```

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
    A() = delete;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a) {
        os << "x: " << a.x << " y: " << a.y;
        return os;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::allocator<int> alloc;
    auto raw = alloc.allocate(2);
    std::bitset<64> before(*raw);
    before.reset();
    std::cout << "before=" << before << "\n";
    std::cout << "---------------------\n";
    std::cout << "sizeof(A)=" << sizeof(A) << "\n";
    std::cout << "alignof(A)=" << alignof(A) << "\n";
    auto a = reinterpret_cast<A *>(raw);
    a->x = 9;
    a->y = 10;
    std::cout << *a << "\n";
    std::cout << "---------------------\n";
    std::bitset<64> after(*raw);
    std::cout << *a << "\n";
    std::cout << "after=" << after << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you lost me here "then i modified an object of A". There is no object of type `A` in your code

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land, where all results are technically correct, which is the best kind of correctness ;)

Comment: What is your aim? If you want to create an `A` then you need to create an `A`, though its only constructor is deleted....

Comment: trying to emulate a nice typed object from raw memory (from another PCI express device) not from the ram, but was really hoping clean 8 bytes memory aligned by 4 bytes can be returned by std::allocator so i can operate directly on A type.

Comment: `raw` is a pointer to `int`, so the bitset will read that int. It has no idea that there could be two ints at that pointer.

Comment: @RohitVishwakarma Type punning is not allowed in C++.

Comment: you should not change the question according to comments. Now it is unclear if both versions of the code prodcue the same output, different one? Whats your question actually? (why do I not get expected output? how do I get expected output? something else? all at once?)

Comment: Thanks @463035818_is_not_a_number - 2nd version of code produces expected output of 0000000000000000000000000000100100000000000000000000000000001010

Comment: but then its part of an answer rather than the question. You could post an answer for your own question if you like. If you leave it in the quesiton, I wonder, what is your question now, after the edit?

Comment: ok makes sense, I didn't know I could answer my question,stackoverflow newbie, let me correct it.

Comment: @RohitVishwakarma please do not edit your questions to post updates showing fixed code. If you want to show the fixed code, remove the edit and post the code as an answer instead. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't see any undefined behviour here.

The actual problem is that you seem to assume that `before(*raw)` creates a bitset with a snapshot of that memory region. But that is not what happens.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset
(you call the unsigned long long constructor)

If you simply write (before `after`):

```cpp
unsigned long long raw_converted_to_long = *raw;
```

You see the value is `9` - this is the reason why the bitset is filled with `9`.